# Calculating Transistor Parameters

Tags: led, transistors

I am using a MJH6284 (Acting as a switch) to power 15 BXRA LED's (Max i = 1000mA, V=9.5) How do I find out the electrical conditions under which the transistor will power the LED, i.e - the supply voltage- Vcc, resistance and voltage at the Base??

Thanks.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, have you looked at the manufacturers datasheet for the transistor? You should do that, and then ask specific questions about items that are not clear to you.

Answer (score 1):

Vcesat is a saturation voltage of the transistor - when the transistor will be on, there will be no more than 1.2V voltage drop over it at 1A current. So you have to have at least 9.5 + 1.2 = 10.7V supply voltage.

Now the current. Graphs on page 5 of [datasheet](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MJH6284-D.PDF) show current gain of 500 at 1A. This means you need *at least* 1A/500=2mA of base current. There will be a 2.8V drop over base emitter when transistor is on - Vbe(on), take this into account when you calculate the resistor value.

To make sure you are switching the transistor on really hard, you want to run the base at somewhat 5 - 10 times the current (10 to 20mA), note Vbe in this case will be at 4V.

To provide more specific information we need to know your supply voltage and the voltage you are switching the transistor on with (microcontroller? 5V, 3.3V?)

Comment: You've given two values for Vbe...I think 2.8V is correct and 4V is too high with a base current of 20mA or so.

Comment: Might be, but it's an upper bound. From the datasheet: Base
−
Emitter Saturation Voltage (IC= 20 Adc, IB= 200 mAdc) VBE(sat) − 4.0 Vdc

Comment: @miceuz - You're reply was quite helpful!, I am planning to Supply a square pulse (through a function generator) of the required voltage. In this case - V at Base of the transistor = 12.5 (considering Vbe = 3, I picked a value between the Vbe(sat) and Vbe(on). Ve= 9.5V (datasheet of the LED) 

Am  I in the right track?

Comment: just don't forget to add base and collector current limiting resistors (ohms law and all that)